# Saving a RDD of key value pairs to a CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of key value pairs which I want to save as a CSV file.

I have written this code to get the RDD from a sequence of files from HDFS.

```
val result = sc.sequenceFile[String,String](filenames)
val rdd_j= result.map(x => x._2)
rdd_j.take(1).foreach(println)
```

This gives me the output as key value pairs. Below is the output.

```
 {"lat":-37.676842,"lon":144.899414,"geoHash8":"r1r19m0s","adminRegionId":2344705 }
```

There are many rows like this.

Now I want to save all rows into a single CSV with keys as columns and their values as cell values. Also some keys may be missing in some rows. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to save it as a local file or on HDFS? What do you want to do with missing values?

Comment: I have tried saving it as csv using saveAsTextFile and write.csv. I want to fill the missing keys as null values in Csv

Comment: I want to save it on hdfs

Answer (score 0):

If all expected columns are known, data can be converted to DataFrame and extracted with 'from_json' function:

```
val value = "{\"lat\":-37.676842,\"lon\":144.899414,\"geoHash8\":\"r1r19m0s\",\"adminRegionId\":2344705 }"
val rdd_j = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(value))

// schema - other expected columns can be added here
val schema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField(name = "lat", dataType = DoubleType, nullable = true),
    StructField(name = "lon", dataType = DoubleType, nullable = true)
  )
)
// action
val df = rdd_j.toDF("value")
val result = df
  .withColumn("fromJson", from_json($"value", schema))
  .select($"fromJson.*")

result.show(false)

result.write.csv("outputPath")
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+
|lat       |lon       |
+----------+----------+
|-37.676842|144.899414|
+----------+----------+
```

**PS** when schema is not known, simple apporach can be used:

```
val result=spark.read.json(rdd_j.toDS())
```